# Positive to negative && Negative to positive in negative base

Tags: c++, algorithm, radix

We are given an array consisting of 0's and 1's. They represent a number in base -2. Example:
    A = (1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
    in decimal = (-2)^0 *(1) + (-2)^1 *(1) + (-2)^2 *(0) + (-2)^3 *(1) + (-2)^4 *(0) = 1 + (-2) + 0 + (-8) + 0 = -9

Now, we need to convert -9 to 9 in base -2. Here's my code so far:

```
vector<int> negative_base(vector<int> &A) {
    //first convert number to decimal base
    int n = 0;
    long count = A.size();
    int power_of_two = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        n+=power_of_two*A[i];
        power_of_two = power_of_two*-2;
    }
    cout<<"number: "<<n<<endl;
    vector<int> base_minus_two;
    n=-n;
    while(n!=0){
        int x;
        if(n<0) {

            x = n%2;
            if(x!=0) x+=2;
            n = (n/-2) +1;

        } else {
            x = n%2;
            n = n/-2;
        }
        base_minus_two.push_back(x);
    }
    return base_minus_two;
}
```

I am asked to return the shortest possible chain of 0's and 1's. However, my code does not always do that. For this example, it generates (1, 0, 1, 1, 1). I think it's fine for this example, yet in some cases it give me long chains while there are other shorter versions. In some cases, it's generating wrong results. For instance, if we have to convert 23 to -23, we get {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1} as a result. However, this number is not equal to -23, but to -63. So, there must be something wrong going on with my calculation. I am following the simplest base conversion algorithm, where you keep dividing until you hit zero, saving all the remainders in a vector as you go on. It's a negative base, so result * (-2) + remainder should give you what you had previously.

```
-23 = (-2) *  12  + 1
 12 = (-2) * (-6) + 0
- 6 = (-2) *   3  + 0
  3 = (-2) * (-1) + 1
 -1 = (-2) *   1  + 1
  1 = (-2) *   0  + 1
```

The result should be (1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), yet I am getting {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1} as I stated. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why are you down-voting this without telling me the reason for doing so? How else am I supposed to ask this question?

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting downvoted partially for readability (not entirely your fault, it's a tricky thing to phrase), and partially because you haven't really shown us what's going wrong - from what I read, the example you gave is one where it works? Also, a description of your algorithm would be nice (deciphering it from source code, not so much.)

Comment: I am following this algorithm: https://mathematics.knoji.com/how-to-convert-a-decimal-number-into-negative-base-a-tutorial/ It is a basic algorithm where you keep dividing the number until you reach zero, saving remainders into a vector as you go along.

Comment: @EdwardPeters, I edited my question, taking into account your suggestions.

Comment: Wait, there can't be any longer and shorter versions: if the base is -2, than there's only one way to present each number, so the answer is either right or wrong, isn't it?

Comment: @YakovL, maybe you're right. I think my solution was totally wrong. It was not generating a different version, but the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

I found what's wrong with the code. Here's the new version:

```
vector<int> negative_base(vector<int> &A) {
//first convert number to decimal base
int n = 0;
long count = A.size();
int power_of_two = 1;
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
    n+=power_of_two*A[i];
    power_of_two = power_of_two*-2;
}
cout<<"number: "<<n<<endl;
vector<int> base_minus_two;
n=-n;
while(n!=0){
    int x;
    if(n<0){
        x = n%2;
        if(x!=0){ x+=2;
        n = (n/-2) +1;
        }else{
            n = (n/-2);
        }

    }else{
        x= n%2;
        n = n/-2;

    }
    cout<<"n: "<< n <<" x: "<<x<<endl;
    base_minus_two.push_back(x);

}
return base_minus_two;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic to test if remainder is negative is wrong (and you can split into sub functions).

```
struct div_with_positive_remainder_t
{
    int quot;
    int rem;
};

div_with_positive_remainder_t div_with_positive_remainder(int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("division by zero");
    int r = x % y;
    if (r < 0) {
        r += std::abs(y);
    }
    int q = (x - r) / y;
    return {q, r};
}

std::vector<int> to_negbase(int n, int negbase = -2)
{
    std::vector<int> res;

    while (n != 0) {
        auto div = div_with_positive_remainder(n, negbase);
        res.push_back(div.rem);
        n = div.quot;
    }
    return res;
}
```

And

```
int to_int(const std::vector<int> &digits, int base = -2) {
    int res = 0;
    int power = 1;
    for (auto digit : digits){
        res += power * digit;
        power *= base;
    }
    return res;
}

std::vector<int> negative_base(const std::vector<int> &v)
{
    return to_negbase(-to_int(v));
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/BPDcvT)

Comment: If you note, I am checking if n is negative, not the remainder. n is the decimal number that's being changed in the while loop. And my program generates the exact same output as yours.

Comment: You fix it in your answer, but it was your problem.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. Got it.